# Power distribution problem in multi-camera usb array

Tags: electrical-engineering, power

**Problem Summary**

My MacBook Pro (development system) can successfully capture images from 24 cameras in the multi camera assembly we have assembled. But when our assembly is attached to a new Raspberry Pi 400 (target deployment system), Linux only mounts up to 18  of the 24 available cameras.

The RPi system log sometimes shows:

**“USB Device over current status detected”**

at boot up time if the assembly is already connected,  or at attachment time if the USB cable is connected after boot up.

I suspect that this problem may be a power related problem, but I don't know how to diagnose this problem, nor which steps I must take to repair the problem.

In trial and error Attempts to access more of the cameras on the Pi, I have tested configurations in which additional power input is provided to the hubs.  But these trials have not succeeded.

**Details and Research**

Our multi-camera array is made of 24 or 18 USB cameras and 4 to 5 USB 7-port hubs, that are attached to a controlling computer (Mac or RPi400) via a single USB cable.

The hubs can be optionally powered using USB-c cables.

I have attached this assembly to both my MacBook Pro (development system), and to a Raspberry Pi 400 (target deployment system). While all 24 cameras are accessible when connected to the Mac, The RPI will only detect up to 18 cameras, and sometimes it won't even find that many.

USB Camera array configurations:
Note that all cameras, hubs, cables and the USB port on the computers are all rated  USB3.

[image: 24 camera spoke configuration]
[image: 24 camera daisy chain configuration]
[image: 18 camera spoke configuration]
[image: 18 camera daisy chain configuration]

**What I’ve tried:**

I have tried connecting external power to zero up to all of the hubs.  I have tried them arranged in both spoke and daisy chain configurations shown for both 24 and 18 cameras.

I can put USB amp-voltmeters between any 2 USB devices, as well as on the power inputs to the hubs when they are receiving external power.

With external power to all hubs, the meter between the master hub and the computer reads a steady 5.15V and 0amps.

I am guessing that the difference between the Mac and the RPi response may have something to do with how much voltage or amperage the RPi USB port can handle, and that those values are different for the MacBook Pro.

What suggestions can you offer as to what Voltage and Amperage measurements should be measured, and where to measure them to determine what is causing the hardware errors.

Comment: Probably you'll get a better chance if you migrate this question to the Electronics Stack Exchange (you'll probably find there more knowledgeable people on the subject). Also, is there a difference between the 4 images? I couldn't spot any at first glance.